# Python 3 Regex 8 numbers only

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use regex to verify input. It should accept 8 and only 8 digits (no spaces letters etc). For example:

```
88884444, 55551234
```

I tried this but it seems to accept if i put more than 8 digits (if I add letters after that it also accepts)
Thanks

```
r'^[0-9]{8,8}'
```

Comment: where is your python code?

Comment: Use start/end anchors (`^......$`).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Comment: chill lol, forgot to paste the code

Comment: Still not enough code. How are you using that?

Comment: @johnll added, thanks!

Comment: i guess `\d{8}` should work? try that by `re.findall('\d{8}', 'your string')`

Comment: `^\d{8}$` will work

Comment: Your "for example" string - should it accept that or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem with your current regex wiz `r'^[0-9]{8,8}'`:

1. `{8,8}` minimum and maximum length you want is 8 so you can make it exact 8 like `{8}`, no need to have range
2. Current regex has condition to check beginning of string but you have not defined end of string which can be defined using symbol `$` which is allowing comma separated numbers so to avoid that you can simply add `$` at the end in your current regex like `r'^[0-9]{8}$'` and it will fix the issue. However, you can still optimize regex using `\d` instead of providing range from `[0-9]` as you're using all the numbers so regex can be further simplified to `"^[0-9]{8}$"`, also provided sample code below.

**code:**

```
import re

in_str = "48848484"

if re.match(pattern="^\d{8}$", string=in_str): print("number is correct")
else: print("wrong phone number")
```